# Input Search Layout Broken in IE6 and input img src not displaying

Tags: search, layout, internet-explorer-6

Yes, another stupid IE6 problem.  Unfortunately I cannot turn a blind-eye to this one.  The input button is not showing up in IE6 but is working in all other browsers and the layout is breaking as well. To see the problem online, please visit [the website](http://chickenofthesea.com/company.aspx). Again, I am only seeing the problem in IE6.  As it's loading, it's inline; but when the page is done loading, it breaks.  On the homepage it seems to be working fine... Any help would be great!

Here is the code for the search field:

```html
<li class="inputSearch">
    <input type="text" id="search" runat="server" title="search" value="search" class="fieldSearch" onfocus="Clear()" onkeydown="testEnterKey(event);" />
    <div class="buttonSearch">
        <input type="image" src="media/images/layout/button-search.png" name="btnSearch" id="btnSearch" onclick="javascript:return SubmitSearch();" />
    </div>
</li>
```

Here is the CSS affiliated with these fields:

```css
.inputSearch {
    background: transparent url('../../media/images/layout/bg-search.png') no-repeat top left;
    width: 99px;
    height: 27px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 6px 0px 7px 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
}
.fieldSearch {
    border: none;
    color: #000;
    width: 85px;
}
.buttonSearch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    left: 0px;
    top: 9px;
}
.navspace {
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

The following is also applied from a special `ie.css` stylesheet:

```css
#topnav ul li.inputSearch {
    width: 109px;
    float: left;
    top: -4px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright i think got it all fixed now...

the search box was breaking due to using 'jquery.pngFix.js'. tweaked the code to not apply transparency to the search box background alone - and shazaam it's displaying inline.

Comment: Sounds like it's a `HasLayout` issue.  I don't know about `jquery.pngFix.js` but I assume it uses the ActiveX CSS filter trick to render PNGs with alpha transparency, but I'm pretty sure a side effect of that is that it will give the element "Layout".  (This whole `HasLayout` mess and its effects on the actual layout of your page is the most horrible, non-standard quirk of IE's rendering engine.)

Comment: the jquery.pngFIX.js file was applying the png alpha fix to all pngs on the site - just had to exclude the background image for the search bar image and that seemed to do the trick.  thanks for your input @Daniel!